# Visual studio: Remove all break points in visual studio 2010 express

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to remove all breakpoints in visual studio 2010 express? I tried "Ctrl + Shift +F9" and "Alt D +D " as mentioned in this web site, but these didn't work.

Comment: i dont know where all i have put breakpoints. i cant do F9.

Answer (score 8):

By default VWD Express is in Basic setting mode.
Go to Tools--> Settings-->

Change from Basic ---> Expert Settings

Answer (score 1):

Mine is "ctrl + shift + R"

Check your shortcut.  (In 2008) Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

in "Show Commands containing" type: `deleteallbreakpoints`

Answer (score 1):

**Is not** available in the Express edition:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft4yk3a3(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft4yk3a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express

Comment: Is it possible to click on the breakpoint Icon? If so, you can add and delete breakpoints, by simply clicking on each Icon along the breakpoint column and it will disappear.